# Extract a number from the middle of a multi-line string?

Tags: c++, regex, string, tags

I'm working on a C++ program and I need to read a piece of meta-data from a TIF file.  The meta-data is a string that looks like the following:

```
<GDALMetadata>
  <Item name="BANDWIDTH"></Item>
  <Item name="CENTER_FILTER_WAVELENGTH"></Item>
  <Item name="DATA_SET_ID">&amp;quot;LRO-L-LOLA-4-GDR-V1.0&amp;quot;</Item>
  <Item name="FILTER_NAME"></Item>
  <Item name="INSTRUMENT_ID">&amp;quot;LOLA&amp;quot;</Item>
  <Item name="INSTRUMENT_NAME">&amp;quot;LUNAR ORBITER LASER ALTIMETER&amp;quot;</Item>
  <Item name="MISSION_NAME"></Item>
  <Item name="NOTE"></Item>
  <Item name="PRODUCER_INSTITUTION_NAME">&amp;quot;GODDARD SPACE FLIGHT CENTER&amp;quot;</Item>
  <Item name="PRODUCT_CREATION_TIME">2017-09-15</Item>
  <Item name="START_TIME">2009-07-13T17:33:17</Item>
  <Item name="STOP_TIME">2016-11-29T05:48:19</Item>
  <Item name="OFFSET" sample="0" role="offset">1737400</Item>
  <Item name="SCALE" sample="0" role="scale">0.5</Item>
</GDALMetadata>
```

I need to extract the `scale` value (which in this case is 0.5).  My first attempt was to use regex as follows:

```
float scale = 1;
std::regex rgx("*<Item name=\"SCALE\"*>(.*?)</Item>*");
std::smatch match;       
if (std::regex_search(metadata.begin(), metadata.end(), match, rgx)) {
    scale = static_cast<float>(std::atof(match.str().c_str()));
};
```

This did not work, and I'm unsure why.  I'm very inexperienced with regex.

Obviously this looks like HTML but as I only need this one specific field I was thinking it should be simpler to simply try to extract that directly.

Comment: That looks like XML. Use an XML parser, not ad hoc regular expressions.

Comment: You have a bunch of extra `*` characters in the regexp. Why? The only one that belongs is in `.*?`

Comment: Kind of reminds me of this question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4581301)

Comment: @Barmar yes you're right, I was being foolish.  I'm using rapidxml and its working great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that using `std::regex` is to assume too much of the future format of the metadata, given that it is an XML text. XML can be shuffled, contain breaks and be in different order.

I would lean towards using a library that can parse and handle XML like libxml2 or boost::property_tree

[Link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/property_tree.html).

The following example parses your metadata and prints the scale.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

std::string metadata = R"(
<GDALMetadata>
  <Item name="BANDWIDTH"></Item>
  <Item name="CENTER_FILTER_WAVELENGTH"></Item>
  <Item name="DATA_SET_ID">&amp;quot;LRO-L-LOLA-4-GDR-V1.0&amp;quot;</Item>
  <Item name="FILTER_NAME"></Item>
  <Item name="INSTRUMENT_ID">&amp;quot;LOLA&amp;quot;</Item>
  <Item name="INSTRUMENT_NAME">&amp;quot;LUNAR ORBITER LASER ALTIMETER&amp;quot;</Item>
  <Item name="MISSION_NAME"></Item>
  <Item name="NOTE"></Item>
  <Item name="PRODUCER_INSTITUTION_NAME">&amp;quot;GODDARD SPACE FLIGHT CENTER&amp;quot;</Item>
  <Item name="PRODUCT_CREATION_TIME">2017-09-15</Item>
  <Item name="START_TIME">2009-07-13T17:33:17</Item>
  <Item name="STOP_TIME">2016-11-29T05:48:19</Item>
  <Item name="OFFSET" sample="0" role="offset">1737400</Item>
  <Item name="SCALE" sample="0" role="scale">0.5</Item>
</GDALMetadata>)";

using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main() {
    std::istringstream input( metadata );
    ptree tree;
    read_xml(input, tree);
    auto items = tree.get_child("GDALMetadata", ptree());
    for (const auto& f: items) {
        auto p = f.second;
        std::string name = p.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.name", "");
        if ( name=="SCALE" ) { 
            std::cout << "Scale: "<< p.data() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Results in

```
Program stdout
Scale: 0.5
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/K94EW9YMf

Comment: I ended up going with rapidxml instead but I agree that using an actual xml parser was the correct solution here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the substring between the 2 delimiters `role="scale">` and `</Item>`, firstly you can remove all `</Item>` instances that are before `role="scale">`, so the substring works correctly, then find the substring between `role="scale">` and `</Item>` using `metadata.substr()` and `metadata.find()`.

```
#include <string>

float scale = 1;
while(metadata.find("</Item>") < metadata.find("role=\"scale\">"){
  metadata.replace(metadata.find("</Item>"), 7, "");
}
if(metadata.find("role=\"scale\">") != string::npos && metadata.find("</Item>") != string::npos){
  scale = stof(metadata.substr(metadata.find("role=\"scale\">") + 13, metadata.find("</Item>") - metadata.find("role=\"scale\">") - 13));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex string literal should be this instead:

`"<Item name=\"SCALE\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/Item>"`

IOW, drop the leading and trailing `*`, you don't need them.  And use `[^>]*` instead of just `*` to ignore everything up to but not including `>` after `"SCALE"`. And you need to escape the `/` in `</Item>` (in the regex itself, not in the string literal).

That being said, `match.str()` will return the entire substring that matched the regex, not the value in the `(.*?)` group as you are expecting.  Thus, `std::atof()` will receive an invalid string and fail. To extract just the group value, use `match[1].str()` instead.

Lastly, consider using `std::stof()` instead of `atof()`.

Try this:

```
float scale = 1;
std::regex rgx("<Item name=\"SCALE\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/Item>");
std::smatch match;       
if (std::regex_search(metadata.cbegin(), metadata.cend(), match, rgx)) {
    scale = std::stof(match[1].str());
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/JoXz5Z-MH)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this the old fashioned way.  Read strings until you find the one with the word "scale", then parse this one in more detail:

```
std::istringstream metadata_stream(metadata_string);
std::string metadata_text_line;
bool found = false;
while (std::getline(metadata_text_line, metadata_stream))
{
    if (metadata_text_line.find("SCALE") != std::string::npos)
    {
        static const char    key_text[] = "\"scale\">";
        std::string::size_type position = metadata_text_line.find(key_text);
        if (position != std::string::npos)
        {
             std::string::npos value_start_position = (position + sizeof(key_text) - 1U);
             end_position = metadata_text_line.find(value_start_position, "<");
             std::string scale_text = metadata_text_line.substr(value_start_position,
                  end_position - value_startOposition);
             //...
        }
    }
}
```

This code presents a general idea or solution; there may be issues with it.